# PlayerPrefs to save setActive state

Tags: c#, monodevelop, unity-game-engine, gameobject

I have some script that is run from my Game scene which hides a gameObject on my Menu scene. However each time the game is closed and reopened the gameObject in my Menu scene is set back to active. I want the gameObject that's been hidden to remain hidden, even through a game reload. This is the code that I have at the moment.

```
     DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);
     SceneManager.LoadScene("sceneSelectBeta");
     GameObject[] gameObjectArray = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag ("Level2Block");
     foreach(GameObject go in gameObjectArray) {
         go.SetActive (false);
         PlayerPrefs.????? ("?????", ?????);
     }
     DestroyObject(gameObject);
```

I use PlayerPrefs to save other information in my project, but I'm not sure how to implement it in this case, any help or advice would be much appreciated.

UPDATE 2.

Current code with playerprefs, will compile but still doesn't save object state.

```
PlayerPrefs.SetInt ("Set Active", 1);

DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);
GameObject[] gameObjectArray = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag ("Level2Block"); //find game object with tag
foreach(GameObject go in gameObjectArray) {
    go.SetActive (false);
    bool active = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Set Active" , 1) == 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You might want to do something like `PlayerPrefs.SetInt(go.Name, 0);` to recall that they are inactive (using 0 for false, 1 for true).  When you load your scene, in one of your `Start` methods, loop through it in the same way, and do something like

```
 foreach(GameObject go in gameObjectArray) {
     bool active = PlayerPrefs.GetInt(go.Name) == 1;
     go.SetActive (active);
 }
```

Comment: It annoys me that PlayerPrefs doesn't support saving a bool value, so I usually end up writing a wrapper that define True and False as 1 and 0 so I can still use bool logic with the class, and extend it with SetBool and GetBool methods.

Comment: Thanks for the advice @Cody at the moment what I have to try and save the object state is included in UPDATE 2, it will compile with no errors, but still the object is re-enabled when the game is reloaded

Comment: When Unity loads a scene, it loads it just as it was saved before you compiled.  You aren't going to be able to preserve a game object being active or not.  You're going to need loading code somewhere to check the state from PlayerPrefs and manually set it.

Answer (score 1):

After the help from the people below, some soul searching through google and ultimately this tutorial video - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uw0kZ72zCvE I was able to resolve the issue